# SQL difference between two datetime columns

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, date-arithmetic

I have a dataset with 2 columns of `datetime` datatype as shown here:

[image]

I want to take the difference between the two dates and I try it with this code:

```
Select 
    *, 
    original_due_date - due_date as difference
from 
    Table
```

However I'm not sure if the same would suffice as this is a datetime and not just date.

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Desired output

[image]

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a `datetime` data type.  Do you mean `timestamp`?  And if so, what results do you want?  Just in days?  As an interval?  In some other. unit?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: The result of subtracting a `timestamp` from a `timestamp` is an `interval`

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, basically I want to take the difference between them and arrive the result in days. (eg 21-Apr-2021 - 22-Apr-2021 = 1 day) So I need the difference column to be number of days. Hope I made sense!

Comment: Does `07-01-2021` mean January 7th, or July 1st?

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Hi @jarlh 7 here is month July.

Answer (score 0):

The question was originally tagged Postgres, so this answers the original question.

Presumably, you are storing the values as `timestamp`s.  If you just want the results in days, then convert to `date`s and take the difference:

```
Select t.*,
       (t.original_due_date::date - t.due_date::date) AS difference
from Table t;
```

If you want fractional days, then a pretty simple method is to extract the "epoch", which is measured in seconds, and use arithmetic:

```
Select t.*,
       ( extract(epoch from t.original_due_date - 
         extract(epoch from t.due_date
       ) / (24.0 * 60 * 60) AS decimal_days
from Table t;
```

Comment: my apologies, apparently hiveSQL does not allow use of ":". I had overlooked to mention the same.

Answer (score 0):

transform timestamps to seconds (unix_timestamp), calculate difference and divide by `(60*60*24)` to get days

```
select  (unix_timestamp(original_due_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm')-unix_timestamp(due_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'))/(60*60*24) as difference_days
 from (select '07-01-2021 00:00' as due_date,  '02-10-2020 00:00' as original_due_date) t
```

Result:

```
-507
```